# How to use Bottom Navigation with Navigation Drawer

Tags: java, android, xml, layout

I am trying to add navigation drawer with bottom navigation view. I have full screen activities for all bottom navigation view fragments. And I have app icon top left side. I want to open navigation drawer when user click on that icon. So How can I implement that?

I tried with DrawerLayout. But it includes the toolbar. And I tried to open new Activities on click of item of Navigation drawer but it gives IllegleStateException.

Comment: Please create a [mre]

Answer (score 0):

I shared the following code below. You have to put the hamburger menu icon for Nav Drawer in the toolbar and a NavigationView inside the DrawerLayout which has a child (ListView, RecyclerView, ExpandableListView etc.) to be filled programmatically or you can just set static items in the NavigationView by setting the menu in NavigationView. Hope that helps. Do ask if you have any more queries.

```
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/colorActivityBackground"
        android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:layoutDirection="locale"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:textDirection="locale">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/topbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"
                app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
                app:contentInsetRight="0dp"
                app:contentInsetStart="0dp"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </FrameLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:maxWidth="320dp">

        <ExpandableListView
            android:id="@+id/navList"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:groupIndicator="@null" />

    </com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. But bottom navigation view which is in main_activity and I am loading fragments in the main frame layouts. And that all activities are full screen activities. I just want to click on image which is in main_activity and open navigation drawer